# edit card detail on stripe only expire month

Tags: php, validation, stripe-payments

I have created a customer with theire card detail and store in stripe account
when I fetch result from stipe it's giving me last 4 digits of the card and not give me CVV,
Now I want to update my card details with only expire month without reentring my card and CVV detail,

But when I perform it's giving me stripe validation error card number invalid and CVV number is required.

I used https://js.stripe.com/v2/ to generate a token and that token I use for creating and updating card information.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken']) && $_POST['stripeToken'] != "") {
    
    /*Create Customer Account through Stripe*/
    
    // Set secret key
    
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX"); //replace your secreet key of stripe here
    
    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    
    try {
        $cu = \Stripe\Customer::update(
            CUSTOMER_TOKEN, // stored in your application
            ['source' => $_POST['stripeToken']]
        );
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        
        $body = $e->getJsonBody();
        $err = $body['error'];
        $error = $err['message'];
        
    }
    
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script>
$('#editCard').validate({
    rules: {
        craditcard: {
            required: true,
        },
        cvv: {
            required: true,
        },
        month: {
            required: true,
        },
        year: {
            required: true,
        },
        card_full_name: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        craditcard: {
            required: "Please enter cradit card number"
        },
        cvv: {
            required: "Please enter cvv number"
        },
        month: {
            required: "Please select month"
        },
        year: {
            required: "Please select year"
        },
        card_full_name: {
            required: "Please enter card full name"
        },
    },
    submitHandler : function(){
        
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX');
        
        var error = false;
        var msg = ''
        var ccNum = $('#craditcard').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#cvv').val(),
        expMonth = $('#expireMonth').val(),
        expYear = $('#expireYear').val(),
        name = $('#card_full_name').val();
        
        
        // Validate the number:
        if (!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
            error = true;
            msg = 'The credit card number appears to be invalid.';
            alert(msg);
        }
        
        // Validate the CVC:
        if (!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
            error = true;
            msg = 'The CVC number appears to be invalid.';
            alert(msg);
        }
        
        // Validate the expiration:
        if (!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
            error = true;
            msg = 'The expiration date appears to be invalid.';
            alert(msg);
        }
        
        
        if (!error) {
            $('.page-load').show();
            // Get the Stripe token:
            Stripe.card.createToken({
                number: ccNum,
                cvc: cvcNum,
                exp_month: expMonth,
                exp_year: expYear,
                name : name,
            }, stripeResponseHandler);
        }
        
    }
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response){
    if (response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
    } else {
        var f = $("#editCard");
        var token = response.id;
        f.append('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="' + token + '" />')
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'edit_card.php',
            data: $("#editCard").serialize(),
            success: function (output) {
                $('.page-load').hide();
            } 
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when I update only expire month `Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)` and `Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)` stripe validation gives me error so I could not generate the token and without the token I cannot edit the card information.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm only seeing your code create a *new* Token and attach it to an existing Customer, but not update an existing Card token

> Now I want to update my card details with only expire month

To do this, you'd have to use Stripe PHP server-side and call the Card Update API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/update

In the parameters on the API ref page, it shows you how you'd pass `exp_month` and `exp_year`.

2. You shouldn't be using Stripe.js v2, as it was deprecated years ago. I'd highly recommend integrating Stripe Elements.
3. "*when I fetch result from stipe it's giving me last 4 digits of the card and not give me CVV*"

This is expected, fetching a Token on Stripe never returns the CVC or card number, for PCI compliance reasons.